# Lighttpd mod_rewrite to Apache Mod_rewrite

Tags: linux, mod-rewrite, apache2, lighttpd

I am looking for some help here. I am trying to convert lighttpd mod_rewrite to apache mod_rewrite

Here it is.
Lighttpd

```
    url.rewrite-once = (
"/torrent/([0-9A-F]{2,2})([0-9A-F]{2,2})([0-9A-F]{36,36}).*" => "/t3/$1/$2/$3.torrent",
)
```

I look up multiply tutorials of apache's mod_rewrite but really no help.

Here what I came up with:

```
RewriteRule ^/torrent/ ([0-9A-F]{2,2})/ ([0-9A-F]{2,2})/ ([0-9A-F]{36,36})/* => /t3/$1/$2/$3.torrent
```

If anybody can help me convert this, it would be an blessing, thankyou

all I get when I put this in is error code 500, mod_rewrite is enabled but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

[Apache’s mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) syntax is a little different:

```
RewriteRule Pattern Substitution [flags]
```

The parts are separated by one or more whitespace characters and `[`*`flags`*`]` is optional.

So try this:

```
RewriteRule ^/torrent/([0-9A-F]{2})/([0-9A-F]{2})/([0-9A-F]{36}) /t3/$1/$2/$3.torrent
```